# Get focused form field id in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, autosuggest

I am currently modifying an out-of-the-box php/jQuery autosuggestion script. I am struggeling with getting the script to work with multiple text input fields.
It is originally made to work with ONE field.

Here is the originale script and form code:

```
function suggest(inputString){
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
    } else {
    $('#city').addClass('load');
        $.post("autosuggest.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                $('#city').removeClass('load');
            }
        });
    }
}

function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#city').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 0);
}
```

The approach to modify the script to work with multiple input fields, i believe, would be to get the focused form elements' id and then do something like this:

```
function getFocusID() {
    // get the focused form field id here
}

if(focusedID == "city") {
    //Script for form field with "city" as id

    function suggest(inputString){
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
        } else {
        $('#city').addClass('load');
            $.post("autosuggest.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                    $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                    $('#city').removeClass('load');
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#city').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 0);
    }
} // code for input id "city" END

// And now create if else statements for the other 4 input text fields, filling them with the code above.
```

Am i thinking correct here? Or is there any other more efficient way to do this?
And if this is the correct approach, how  do i get the inpud id of the focused input text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the [activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.activeElement) :

```
function getFocusID() {
    return document.activeElement.id;
}
```